# Adjusting the trip current on a Bertan Model 1755

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, experimental-technology

The Bertan Model 1755 is a high-voltage power supply that was used in many experiments at SLAC. As far as I can tell, it was manufactured specifically and exclusively for experiments at SLAC. The paper [The MAC detector](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-9002(89)91327-2) mentions that it can be set to trip at a specific current:

> Each supply is set to trip off and/or sound an alarm if the average current exceeds a preset limit ($0.1$ to $1.0\ \mathrm{mA}$).

but no paper I can find mentions how this is done. As you can see in the image at the bottom of the post, by default it trips at 80% full scale on the meter, but this would only allow the current limit to be set to $0.8\ \mathrm{mA}$ or less than $80\ \mathrm{\mu A}$.

How can the trip current be more finely adjusted on these high-voltage power supplies, as the paper describes?

Note: I added the [particle-physics] tag because these high-voltage power supplies were used exclusively on HEP experiments, so I am hoping to attract the attention of some experimental physicists that worked on these experiments.

[image]

Comment: If someone has a copy of the manual for this power supply, that would be even better. I kind of doubt one exists in electronic form, though, so I've asked about the specific question I have instead.

Comment: Have you tried contacting SLAC ?  They might have some documents.

Comment: @StephenG I'm looking into it, but I haven't any idea of *who* to contact at SLAC.

Answer (score 3):

This power supply is a NIM module, the front looks something like this:

[image: Bertran1755P]

The knob on the top left selects the current range that is displayed on the meter. As it says on the front, the power supply trips at 80% of that range. Thus, turning that knob changes both the dynamic range of the display and the allowed current before a trip.

Comment: Hi @rfl. The $1\ \mathrm{mA}$ quoted in the paper would correspond to 100% full scale on the highest range. And I have one specimen that is set to trip at 100% full scale on one channel and 80% full scale on the other. So this is apparently adjustable, somehow. My application requires tripping at 100% full scale, but unfortunately the single specimen I have that trips at that scale is the wrong polarity.

Comment: Ah. Hm. OK, then I'm out of my comfort zone. Sorry, don't have a manual - these I literally found in our attic ;) Might be adjustable via the analog connector on the back, but to "code" that would certainly require the manual.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently SLAC had a lot of these made- I've seen them all over the place.